# PDFBox not printing signature over javax.print api

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox

Given a digitally signed PDF file with a signature, I'd like to print this document on paper.

Using PDFBox with the following code I am able to print the document, except for that the signature is not ending up on the thin, bleached sheets of dead tree. The positioning of text around it does not change. So it seems aware of that there should be something there, yet it is not printed.

```
  import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
  import javax.print.PrintService;
  import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
  import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
  import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

  InputStream pdf = getPDFInputStreamSomeHow();
  PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(pdf);
  PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(pdDocument);

  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  job.setPrintService(service);
  job.setPageable(pageable);
  job.print(attrs);
```

It seems that PDFBox actually does support this kind of signature, because when I use `org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer` to render the page to a `BufferedImage`, the signature is rendered just as it is in my regular PDF reader (Acrobat or Evince).

How can I get PDFBox to render the signature correctly when printing? I'd rather not mess about with printing `BufferedImage`'s since it would split the document into multiple print jobs and make me responsible for the quality of the rendered image sent to the printer.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using and what OS are you using and can you share the PDF? Some printing problems are solved by using the 4-parameter PDFPageable constructor, with the last parameter set to your wished dpi, e.g. 300 (yes, that makes you responsible for the quality of the rendered image sent to the printer). Other printing problems may go away by switching off or on the advanced printing in the "extended" dialogbox. (Don't have the exact words, there's a JIRA issue, but JIRA is down)

Comment: Here's the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3729 , this may or may not be the cause.

Comment: I cannot share this PDF as it contains confidential information and generating a new one without is a hassle. But that's no problem because your suggestion worked! Please post using the 4-arg constructor as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Done. If you ever experience the effect with a non confidential file, please attach it to the mentioned issue (if still open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for your problem is to use the 4-parameter constructor of `PDFPageable` with a non-0 value:

```
public PDFPageable(PDDocument document, Orientation orientation, boolean showPageBorder, float dpi)
```

setting the 4th parameter to a useful number like 300 results in the image being be rasterized at the given DPI. So for you, the call would be

```
PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(pdDocument, Orientation.AUTO, false, 300);
```

A possible cause of printing problems are being tracked in issue [PDFBOX-3729](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3729). That issue has also another workaround for windows users.